# Does ASICBOOST only work on Bitmain miners and how does one enable it on these systems?

Tags: mining-profitability, miner-configuration, antminer, asicboost

From what I read ASICBOOST gives you a 30% better hash rate, does this only work on all or certain Bitmain asic miners? And how does one enable this hidden feature in these miners?

Comment: Bitmain has clearly stated that their miners do NOT use asicboost and there is no solid proof that they do, just one core developer saying so. There is a 99% chance that they don't use it outside of experimentation on testnet.

Comment: @Markasoftware: At least in his [initial email](https://lists.linuxfoundation.org/pipermail/bitcoin-dev/2017-April/013996.html) Maxwell does not claim that they do use it. He merely states that he has discovered that chips implement it, and that the exploitation of the bug could give an unfair advantage to the respective user. I'm curious how you're so certain that they haven't used it. Silicon space is pretty costly, why would they put it there if they don't use it? It also fits the facts pretty well especially in light of Wu "liking LN" but blocking SegWit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Our ASIC chips, like those of some other manufacturers, have a circuit design that supports ASICBOOST." [- Bitmain statement](https://blog.bitmain.com/en/regarding-recent-allegations-smear-campaigns/)

Bitmain claims that it wasn't used on mainnet. It is currently unknown how to make use of the feature. Likely, you'd need custom firmware and software.

---

Edit: Here's someone on reddit describing how to activate ASICBOOST: https://www.reddit.com/r/Bitcoin/comments/63yo27/some_circumstantial_evidence_supporting_the_claim/dfy5o65/

Answer (score 1):

Both [Bitmain](https://blog.bitmain.com/en/new-firmware-activate-overt-asicboost-bm1387-antminer-models/) and [Braiins](https://twitter.com/braiins_systems/status/1055153228772503553) have now released S9 firmware that enables overt AsicBoost.